# When saving a file already in a list it asks for it to be renamed

Tags: list, infopath, save

I have a list on sharepoint where Infopath forms are stored.

Multiple people are working on the forms but not at the same time.

When the second person has added there part to the form they try and save.

He is only selecting the Save button because this item is already on the list.

When he hits save he gets the below error message.

Any insight to this problem at all is appreciated.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check a couple of settings on the library.

In Versioning:

Versioning should be enabled.

Does the library require Check Out? (No is best IMHO) If so, did the last person check in the changes (this can cause an item to be locked for editing).

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for that. Versioning was disabled and im waiting for users to resume testing.